# Problemas com grid no Bootstrap versão 3

Tags: css, html5, bootstrap-3, less

Estou com problemas de grid no meu html com bootstrap ele deveria ficar assim 
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]
porem no meu navegador ele fica assim:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

percebam que no meu banner que está dentro da tag `<header>` esta com `height:auto;` justamente para poder aconpanhar o redimencionamento da minha pagina porem não sei onde estou errando segue meu código :

O HTML:

```
<header>
      <div class="container">
         <div class="row">
            <div class="col-md-6">
              <div class="text-left">
                <h3>surpreenda-se</h3>
                <h2>Um tinto leve</h2>
                <h1>e fácil de beber</h1>
              </div>
            </div>

            <div class="col-md-6">
              <img src="images/vinho.png" alt="vinho pedro carvalho">
                <div class="box-right">
                  <div class="text-right">
                    <h3>2012</h3>
                    <h2>Pedro Carvalho</h2>
                    <button type="button">Detalhes</button>
                  </div>
                </div>
            </div>
         </div>
      </div>
    </header>
```

O CSS:

```
/*variaveis*/
@colorLinks: #fff;
@colorHovers: #bd8937;
@colorTexts: #333;
@colorBox: #161515;

/*Functions*/
.radius(@corner: 50px){
    border-radius:@corner ;
    -webkit-border-radius:@corner;
    -moz-border-radius:@corner;
    -o-border-radius:@corner;
}


header{
    background-image: url(../images/background.png);
    width: 100%;
    height: auto;
}


.content-general{
    margin-left: 150px;
}

.text-left{
    color: @colorLinks;
    margin-top: 130px;
}

.text-left h3{
    color: @colorHovers;
}

.text-left h2{
    font-size: 3em
}

.text-left h1{
    font-size: 4em;
}

.box-right{
    color: @colorLinks;
    text-align: left;
    background-color: @colorBox;
    padding: 50px;
    width: 350px;
    margin-top: -450px;
}

.box-right button{
    background-color: @colorHovers;
    padding: 10px 30px;
    border: none;
}

.text-right{
    text-align: left;
    margin-left: 100px;
}
```

OBS: Também gostaria de centralizar essas minhas duas colunas no centro da tela sem ter que usar o `margin-left` tentei usar o `text-align:center` e o `margin:0 auto` mais não funcionou

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Qual a versão do seu bootstrap?

Comment: estou usando a  versao 3

Comment: De início só uma idéia usar o col-sm é mais recomendável. 
Mas vamos se entendi. 

1 -  Se você quer centralizar o texto, tire o class="text-left" e o class="text-right" e mude para class="text-center".

2 - Agora se quer dar uma distância da col da margem direita ou esquerda.
Na primeira coluna <div class="col-md-5 col-md-offset-1"> e na segunda <div class="col-md-5">

Comment: Legal amigo deu certo so que o problema e que nao estou conseguindo deixar igual o layout da primeira imagem como voce pode ver o bavkground termina exatamente no final da imagem do vinho nao sei porque

Comment: Use o comando background-size: cover ou background-size: 100% 100%; no css

Comment: amigo nao funcionou e fora que quando redimenciono ele nao acompanha o background poderiamos conversar pelo hungout ou skype preciso mesmo de uma ajuda de alguem amis experiente pois começei ontem a mexer com bootstrap preciso terminar esse trabalho

Comment: me adiciona no Facebook
https://www.facebook.com/pedr0369

Comment: pronto amigo já te chamei no chat

Comment: Solucionado no skype ^.^

Comment: @PedroFranco e Kirito algum de vocês devia colocar aqui a o solução que resolveu o problema :P... Em de só "Qual a versão do seu bootstrap?". Editem esta resposta sff